# I can't use multiple multi touch functions in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a simple app for android where you pan sideways looking for different objects to click. When you click the objects they disappear and you get a score count.

I've managed to make the separate codes for the click and the pan but if you pan you're not able to click the object. If you click the object though before you pan it all works like a charm.

Code for the panning:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

Game_Background1.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN, swipe_pan);

function swipe_pan(event:TransformGestureEvent):void

{
event.currentTarget.x += event.offsetX;
event.currentTarget.y +0; event.offsetY;    
}
```

Code for the clicking:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

Bunny.addEventListener(PressAndTapGestureEvent.GESTURE_PRESS_AND_TAP, hideBunny);

function hideBunny(event:PressAndTapGestureEvent):void
{
Bunny.visible = false;
Bunny.alpha *= 0.5;
}
```

The code for the clicking is located in an actions layer in the same movieclip as the layer with the clickable object in this case "Bunny".

The code for the panning is then located outside of that movieclip in its own actions layer.

Thankfull for any help I can get with this.

Comment: variables should not start with a capitol letter!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to give a try to [Gestouch](https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch)

Try something like:

```
var panGenture:PanGesture;
panGenture = new PanGesture(Bunny);
panGenture.addEventListener(org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent.GESTURE_BEGAN, onPanHandler);
panGenture.addEventListener(org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent.GESTURE_CHANGED, onPanHandler);

function onPanHandler(event:org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent):void
{
    trace("pan");
}
```

or

```
var tapGesture:TapGesture;
tapGesture = new TapGesture(Bunny);
tapGesture.addEventListener(org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent.GESTURE_RECOGNIZED,   onGestureHandler);
//you can also add tapGesture.numTapsRequired = 2;

function onGestureHandler(event:org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent):void
{
    trace("tap");
}
```